# how to read data from users' google drive in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-drive-api

I followed [example](https://morioh.com/p/67f2eae3adf3) to write file to google drive. Write works and I can see file at google drive. But now when I tried to read or list the files, I am getting null

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart' as signIn;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<void> readFile() async {
    print(' read file');

    final googleSignIn = signIn.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [
      drive.DriveApi.driveFileScope,
      // drive.DriveApi.driveAppdataScope
    ]);
    final signIn.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    print("User account $account");

    final authHeaders = await account!.authHeaders;
    final authenticateClient = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
    final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(authenticateClient);

    drive.DriveList driveList = drive.DriveList();
    // drive.FileList fileList = drive.FileList( kind: 'appDataFolder');
    drive.FileList fileList = drive.FileList( );

    if (driveList == null ) {
      print(' driveList is null');
    } else {
      print(' driveList is not NULL ');
    }

    if ( fileList == null ) {
      print(' fileList is null');
    } else {
      print(' fileList is NOT null');

      List<drive.File>? allFiles =     fileList.files;

      if ( allFiles == null || allFiles.isEmpty ) {
        print(' allFiles is empty ');
      }
      Map<String, dynamic> fileListJson = fileList.toJson();

      if ( fileListJson == null || fileListJson.isEmpty) {
        print(' fileList toJson is null');
      }

    }
  }


  Future<void> saveFile() async {

    final googleSignIn = signIn.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [
      drive.DriveApi.driveFileScope
      // drive.DriveApi.driveAppdataScope
    ]);
    final signIn.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    print("User account $account");

    final authHeaders = await account!.authHeaders;
    final authenticateClient = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
    final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(authenticateClient);

    final Stream<List<int>> mediaStream = Future.value([104, 105]).asStream();
    var media = new drive.Media(mediaStream, 2);
    var driveFile = new drive.File();
    driveFile.name = 'hello.txt';
    final result = await driveApi.files.create(driveFile, uploadMedia: media);
    print("Upload result: $result");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Hello2',
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: saveFile,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.save),
          ),

          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: readFile,
            tooltip: 'show The file listing and contents',
            child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
          ),


        ],
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _headers;
  final http.Client _client = new http.Client();

  GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
  }
}
```

drive.FileList is returning null, it should return all files on google drive as the permission was granted. Tried with drive.DriveApi.driveAppdataScope option also, but to no avail. googleapis: ^5.0.1, google_sign_in: ^5.1.0 are the version of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You use `driveApi` correctly but then you don't use it anymore, instead of writing:

```
drive.DriveList driveList = drive.DriveList();
    // drive.FileList fileList = drive.FileList( kind: 'appDataFolder');
    drive.FileList fileList = drive.FileList( );
```

You should write:

```
var driveFiles = await driveApi.files.list(q: 'mimeType=\'image/jpeg\'')
List<File>? files = driveFiles.files;
for (File file in files!) {
        print(file.id);
        print(file.name);
}
```

(using the mimeType you need)